# Right Triangles and Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose that you have a right triangle $a^2+b^2=c^2$ with integral sides. Given a perimeter $p=a+b+c$, how can you use Lagrange multipliers to determine the maximum length of $a$?

Comment: You can't :) Lagrange multipliers only applies with continuous (differentiable) constraints, not the requirement that you have integers. In the continuous world, you would only get a maximum by taking $a=p/2=c$ and $b=0$.

Comment: How can I use them to find the maximum with continuous variables?

Comment: This is standard Lagrange multipliers. Let $f(a,b,c)$ be the function you want to maximize/minimize, let $g(a,b,c)=0$ be your constraint, and find places on your constraint set where $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are parallel vectors.

Comment: If you do so in this case, you'll find no solutions. That's because Lagrange multipliers can only handle *equality* constraints, not *inequality* constraints, and so you have to deal with the boundary issues (which occur here because you want $a,b,c\ge 0$) separately.

Answer (score 1):

The continuous case has been dealt with by Ted Shifrin in the comments: the maximum is attained at the boundary $a=c=p/2$, $b=0$. Since the perimeter $p$ of a Pythagorean triangle must be even, this also solves the  integer problem *if* we allow degenerate triangles.

Suppose we don't. I'll borrow from the senior thesis [Perimeters of primitive Pythagorean triangles](http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/SeniorProjectArchive/2010/SeniorProject_LindseyWitcosky.pdf) by L. Witcosky. Since $p$ is even, we can work with $p/2$, the semiperimeter. Suppose it factors as $p/2=uv$ with $u<v<2u$. Then 
$$a=2uv-2u^2,\quad b=2uv-v^2,\quad c=2u^2-2uv+v^2 \tag1$$
is a Pythagorean triangle with desired perimeter. To maximize $\max(a,b)$ amounts to minimizing $\min(\sqrt{2}u,v)$: that is, look for the smallest possible $u$, then the smallest possible $v$, and compare the results.